# bulk update mvc grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, grid

I was going through this
   http://weblogs.asp.net/bhaskarghosh/archive/2009/06/18/7128803.aspx
  can anyone help me on how to implement this in mvc3 razor syntax?

I am getting error like ""BookList["" is not valid at start of code block

if I replace <%= with @

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Just replace <% sign with @ and delete this sign %>.

Sample Grid in MVC here "Model.lstEmployees" is a model for binding the grid.

```
<table class="content-wrapper">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayName("Name")
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayName("ID")
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayName("Designation")
        </th>
        <th>
        </th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model.lstEmployees)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.id)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.designation)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.id })
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.id })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

    </script>
</table>
```

Comment: I am getting error like ""BookList["" is not valid at start of code block

Answer (score 0):

In the `<%= %>` format, the `"` are used to "escape" out between code and html, but that isn't necessary in razor.  So in razor, you not only need to change the `<%=` but you also need to remove the `"` so the code would be `BookList[i]` rather than `"BookList[" + i + "]"`